# how can i pivot/ transpose my data in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the following table:

| metrics | uuid | project_id | project_name | values |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| metric a | uuid 1 | row | row | 1 |
| metric b | uuid 2 | row | row | 2 |
| metric c | uuid 1 | row | row | 3 |
| metric c | uuid 3 | row | row | 3 |
| metric a | uuid 3 | row | row | 1 |
| metric b | uuid 3 | row | row | 2 |

I'm trying to get it to look like this in BigQuery using SQL. I think it's probably some combination of pivot/transpose but i'm not sure where to even start

|  | metric a | metric b | metric c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| uuid 1 | 1 |  | 3 |
| uuid 2 |  | 2 | 3 |
| uuid 3 | 1 | 2 | 3 |

What is the best way to go about this? Quite new to sql/bigquery so if the answer is obvious please bear with me!

thank you in advance!

Comment: are you trying to write a SQL query?

Answer (score 1):

Consider below [PIVOT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#pivot_operator) query.

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT uuid, metrics, values 
    FROM sample_table
) PIVOT (SUM(values) FOR TRANSLATE(metrics, ' ', '_') IN ('metric_a', 'metric_b', 'metric_c'));
```

- Since the column name can't have a space in it, make [TRANSLATE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#translate) funtion replace it with a underline.

**Query results**

[image]